# Is it possible to reference a connection string in another connection string?

Tags: web-config, connection-string

We have a project with multiple DLLs. In each DLL, we connect to a database - always the same one for a client.

As a result, we now have 3 near-identical connection strings : one for our web site, one for ado.net, and one for telerik reporting :

```
    <add name="BDConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=500;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CMS.Reporting.My.MySettings.BDConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="KOPWebEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.web.csdl|res://*/Data.web.ssdl|res://*/Data.web.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now it's still manageable, but in the future, we will have more ADO.Net Entity Framework connections, so maybe 10 connection strings by client ?

Is there a way to say, "ok, for this connection string, use the value coming from here" instead of duplicating it ? At least for ADO.Net ?

Or is there a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: Might just be me, but I don't really understand what you're asking for

Comment: Well, I don't want to have to maintain 10 near-identical connection strings for each and every client (one for every entity model). Can I simplify it ?

Comment: Well, you only need 1 connection string per database, so if you put your tables in the same database, you will only need 1 connection string to connect to all of them. Does that help?

Comment: Nope, it does not. Try this : add an ADO.Net entity model to your project, with a few tables. Then add another. Try to reuse the same connection string for both. Now, picture this with 10 entity models. Then, picture it with 30 different connection strings for 30 different clients.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you mentioned Entity Framework.  It is possible to create entity contexts with different SQL connections than the one defined in the application/web config. (I'd have to dig up the code).  However, as far as the more general "have a connection string that actually references another connection string" question, I'd say, if you don't have the source, tough luck.

It'd probably be better if your DLLs didn't reference app/web config settings and, for the classes defined in there, you could pass in either the, the "application key" which has an associated value referencing a connection string, the SQL connection string itself, a SqlConnection instance, or some SqlConnection-Factory-Thing you make up.