# Call connection string into another connection string in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, web-config

I have two connections in the web.config basically they are calling the same database. I want to manage this in  a better manner because change in one config also needs to change the second connection string as well.

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;persist security info=True;user id=test;password=test123;database=db-AUTH" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.csdl|res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.ssdl|res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=db-AUTH;persist security info=True;user id=test;password=test123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My question is, is there any way i can call the connection string into the other connection string.

For example. default connection connection string into db entities something like

```
<add name="dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.csdl|res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.ssdl|res://*/InsuranceFinderModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string= DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443060/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-connection-string-in-another-connection-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not obliged to use connection string defined inside app.config(web.config) file for entity connection. You can change entity connection string at runtime. Read this article for that: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/pass-connection-string-in-run-time-to-entity-framework/ .

Also you can get another connnection string and separete every part of connection string( DataBase,DataSource and etc.) using StringConnectionBuilder class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx.

The solution is: **Get DefaultConnection string and change entity connection at runtime.**